# cin.fail not working when numbers and letters entered

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, g++, std

I am working on a simple data validation as part of inputting numbers to an array. Right now it is working for the most part with the exception of one case - when I enter a number followed by a letter, the error message that I created it thrown, but the number is still entered into the array. Further confusing me is that it is functioning as intended when I compile the program in Xcode, but the issue I'm describing only shows up when I compile the program with g++. Any thoughts would be very appreciated. Here is my function which I think is giving me the issue.

```
float getInput()
{
    float input;
    std::cin >> input;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "type char/str not allowed, enter int" << '\n';
        return getInput();
    }
    else
        return input;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if `123abc` is entered, the input is assigned `123` but then error still throws. Is that right?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but **don't** have this function call itself. Recursive functions can be very powerful, but they're rarely the right solution. Just write a loop: `while (!std::cin) { /* clean up */ std::cin >> input; }`. Or, more commonly, remove the `std::cin >> input;` before the test and put it in the loop condition: `while (!(std::cin >> input)) { /* clean up */ }`;

Comment: @SacrificerXY - correct, I want it to throw the error and not accept the input.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Yea, good call on the recursion, I was mainly trying to be clever and practice using recursion on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out. Basically, this is not the time to be using recursion. I put the if statement in a while loop, added a second cin to the end of the loop, and moved the return out of the loop. That took care of it. Thanks for the suggestion to use a loop instead.